# The type of singularity: $x^4 + y^4 + z^2=0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the singular point $O=(0,0,0) \in X : (x^4 + y^4 + z^2=0) \subset \mathbb C^3$.

Is it a Du Val singurarity?

Is there any algorithm or computer program with which one can determine the type of singularities?

Comment: There's a finite list of families of Du Val singularities up to analytic isomorphism in a paper of Miles Reid, probably called "Du Val Singularities" or something like that. Try looking there.

Comment: @KReiser, Reid's note contains a list of standard forms of equations for Du Val singularities.
What I am asking is how to determine whether one can change a given equation to the standard form.

Comment: I think you could [edit] your post to make that clearer. Knowing you're not just someone walking off the street in to the singularities store for the first time is helpful in figuring out what level to pitch answers at.

Comment: I just want to know how to determine the type of the given singularity.
It would be great if someone let me know where to start.

Comment: Look, I sympathize and I'm generally interested in helping, but it's important that if you're asking your question here on MSE that you give some more background, either about your level of knowledge of the subject or your previous attempts. That's part of [how things work around here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/), and it helps you get better answers. For instance, some folks would be perfectly happy with my first comment, but you require more explanation, and it would help me to know approximately how much you know in order to give you that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a Du Val singularity because its Milnor number is 9, which is greater than 8.
See sec 2.4, chapter 1 of "Introduction to singularities and deformations" by Gert-Martin Greuel, Christoph Lossen, Eugenii I. Shustin for details. You can find some algorithms and programs there.